# Type Theory research groups

Tags: type-theory, recommendations, constructive

Research about type theory, internal languages, intuitionism, constructivism, and proof assistants is, at the moment, not as fashionable as other branches of mathematics are, say for example algebraic geometry and topology. Furthermore, the people who are involved are distributed evenly over mathematics, computer science and philosophy departments. For example, I could not find a single type theory research group in Berlin, even though Berlin has three large universities. At the moment I have a big list of universities lying next to my computer, and I am browsing through each departments website to find out if there is someone in the department who does type theory. But then I realized that, a) I might not be the only person who has this problem, and b) my solution is really time consuming and stupid. So here is my question:

*Where can I find research groups which work on type theory and the semantic of programming languages?* I am interested to know about groups which sit in Germany and England, but of course a list of interest to the general reader of this side could include groups all over the world. I believe that type theory research is rare enough that it is realistic to create such a list.

Comment: Yes, it was supposed to be site. I corrected it.

Comment: you an check https://leanprover.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/224796-Geographic-locality for places. 
And https://leanprover.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/284757-job-postings
(these are not only Lean-specific)

Comment: Perhaps [Meta](https://proofassistants.meta.stackexchange.com/) might be a good place to put this question. In general, a question like “is this Q appropriate for this place?” is perfect for that, and you might have have informative answers (about research groups) there!

Comment: That said, type theory is most popular among computer scientist, for instance the  [research group](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/research/pls/) of [Andrew Pitts](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~amp12/)

Comment: You might be interested in the network list of the [MAP = Mathematics + Algorithms + Proofs](https://mapcommunity.github.io/) project (not fully up-to-date though)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this "meta-question" should probably have been asked on [Meta](https://proofassistants.meta.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: @ErikMD we could debate whether this is on topic for this site, but i really don't think this is appropriate for meta. Meta is for questions specific to the site itself and has much less traffic.

Comment: Is Meta the right place? Should I delete the question and ask it again there.

Comment: In my experience based on other Stackexchange sites, Meta is most likely not the right place to ask this kind of question, it should stay on main. These kinds of "soft" questions that still relate to the topic can be valuable though, and should be made community wiki.

Comment: The question should probably be more about whether this Q is more suitable on https://cstheory.stackexchange.com

Comment: @GuyCoder OK, I agree that Meta would not be a better fit. But it was my only reason for closing this question (in particular, I don't think it's a subjective question, nor an off-topic question, because type-theory is a common foundation for almost all proof assistants, and the OP explicitly spoke about type theory *and* proof assistants, and I'm not sure it would be [on-topic](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on TCS.SE [(see also this FAQ)](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/a/235/51245), while questions that are on-topic on PA.SE actually needs to be refined :)

Comment: So actually, would it look good to you to turn this question/answer in a community wiki answer? which would have the advantage of being easier for PA.SE members to contribute, as opposed to a tag wiki, for example… In which case, I could suggest to add [the URL of this website of the MAP community](https://mapcommunity.github.io/members.html) as a first external link for one such answer, in line with [my previous comment](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/827/type-theory-research-groups#comment1647_827).

Comment: I'm not convinced that this should be reopened: https://proofassistants.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84/why-is-a-question-about-dependent-type-theory-off-topic/87#comment186_87 nor that the OP doesn't know of a more suitable site (or it's meta): https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4384804/510296

Comment: @Rob I believe that categorical logic, type theory and proof assistants are strongly connected, and that this is the right side for my question. Many people who work with type theory also work with proof assistants to implement their type theory (e.g. Andrej Bauer, the HoTT Community). After all, the initiative for this site came from Andrej Brauer, and they do exactly the kind of research I am looking for. I know it is a soft question, and many stackexchange people do not like those, but the answers I have for so far are incredibly helpful to me.

Comment: @Rob You linked a comment which speaks about group theory. But the relation of group theory to proof assistants is fundamentally different than the relation between type theory and assistants. Group theory is just a field of mathematics which can be formalised in assistants, while type theory is the theoretical basis (!) of most proof assistants.

Comment: @Rob Fair enough. It seems like we have different ideas about which kinds of topics this side should discuss. I would argue though, that foundations and semantics are especially important for proof assistants, more than for other programming languages, since they are about *proving* stuff. All the features which one implements does have to be sound and habe to have a strong semnatics. So you cant really exclude that at all.

Comment: Merle, you may be interested in reading: [What is a "closed" or "duplicate" question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10582/282094), and read the sections: "Comments to reopen" and "Editing to reopen" in: [How do you reopen a closed question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/36423/282094).

Comment: @Rob Okay. I just wanted to defend my question a bit, as Guy Coder suggested I should.

Comment: @GuyCoder, see the [top voted answer](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/a/32615/181886) at the link you offered and Catija's comment (even **your** own answer there, 2nd top voted). --- There needs to be an element of "proof assistants" (or theorem providing, etc.) and not simply something used; and more specifically this question is: **"Where can I find research groups ..."** - so it's not about proving or even the theory of which you speak, it's "where are the people".

Comment: @Rob Yes, and "where are the people" questions are the most important kind of question which we can ask each other, in my opinion. We need connections and community much more than we need technical details. It is cool to have a place where you can ask technical questions, but it is not the only thing that counts. I really want to write my thesis in the field of type theory/categorical logic and I really struggle to find "the people". And I bet I am not the only one. What is so wrong about a "where are the people" question?

Comment: I will edit the question tomorrow when I have time. I will include the research groups which I have found with a short description of what they do, and then I will try to reopen it. :)

Comment: Merle, in response to [your last comment](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/827/type-theory-research-groups?noredirect=1#comment1739_827), it is other people who voted to close this question; though I don't disagree with them and have explained the reasons. I've also offered the links explaining this and how to get your question reopened. --- When you ask the same thing again it seems like my previous efforts were unsuccessful, that is fine; ask the others.

Comment: I'm skipping the reopen vote for now, so I can revisit it when Merle has had the opportunity to revise and expand the Question's body as to research groups found.  In its present form it hinges on a premise that such research groups are "rare enough ... to ... list."  Some evidence for that premise would be welcome.

Answer (score 4):

### External links

The following pages mention researchers interested in the foundations or applications of proof assistants:

- Authors participating in the [TYPES](https://sites.google.com/view/thetypesconferences) international conference on Types for Proofs and Programs.
- Research groups involved in the COST Action [EUTypes](https://eutypes.cs.ru.nl/) (2016-2020).
- People listed in the [Network members](https://mapcommunity.github.io/members.html) page of the [MAP (Mathematics = Algorithms + Proofs)](https://mapcommunity.github.io/) project.

Comment: This is a very first version of a possible answer (with just 3 external links for the time being). So the structure that this wiki answer should have should definitely be discussed! (suggestions *and edits* are very welcome :)